# How to use contextPath in html without JSP

Tags: html, contextpath

I want to know how to use contextPath in html code.

For example, if I load html code like below dynamically in runtime how to express contextPath?? (It is html template, no jsp)

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/contextPath/folder1/file1.do">menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contextPath/folder2/file2.do">menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contextPath/folder3/file3.do">menu3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: By default when you add the path in `a` tag, click on the url will append to the running application. If the context is same as running application, you just need to add the url after context

Comment: Thx for reply. You mean click event binding to a tag using jquery on a tag after html template loading?? Is that what I understood??